# Time complexity of function with nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand how to determine big-O and I've found this algorithm and I'm not really sure about my calculations with this one.

```
Compute(A,n,x):
begin
  l=0;
  r=n-1;
  while true do
     while l<r and A[l] < x do
         l=l+1;
     end
     while l<r and A[r] >= x do
         r=r-1;
     end
     if l>=r then
        return
     end
     tmp = A[l];
     A[l]=A[r];
     A[r]=tmp;
     l=l+1;
     r=r-1;
  end
end
```

My guess would be **O(n*log(n))**, but don't have any proper reason why. The way I was thinking...

The inner loops will both have **O(n)**, so I can add those two, still having **O(n)**. And the outer loop will end depending on l, r, which both can grow in the inner loops, so the complexity should be lower than n, but the **log(n)** is basically just a guess.

Could anyone help me understand, how to approach this in a right way?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, changed `r=0` to `r=n-1`. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change initial value of `r` to `n-1` (seems it is silly mistake), you will get `O(n)` procedure similar to Hoare partition (part of Quicksort algorithm).

Just look - left index moves only right, right index moves only left, and loop works until they meet.

`r=0;` has no sense  - routine stops immediately